# Find the area between the curves: $y=x+1, y=-3x+13,y=-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, area

Find the area between the curves: $$y=x+1$$

$$y=-3x+13$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}$$

[image]

I see this when I graph it, and it's not easy for me to understand what variable I should integrate with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Calculate the distances between the points, and use Heron's formula.

Comment: It doesn't matter , both require splitting the area.

Comment: You can use cross product instead, I think that's a bit more pleasant than splitting the region, integrating, etc.

Comment: Unforunately this is for calculus and not linear algebra so I cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition the triangular region $R$ into $R_1$ and $R_2$ where

$$R_1=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:-1\leq x\leq 3 \text{ and }\frac{-x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\leq y\leq x+1\right\}$$
and
$$R_2=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:3\leq x\leq 5\text{ and } \frac{-x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\leq y\leq -3x+13\right\}.$$ Denoting by $A_1$ and $A_2$ the corresponding areas of $R_1$ and $R_2$, we get

$$A_1=\int_{-1}^3\left[(x+1)-\left(\frac{-x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]dx$$
and
$$A_2=\int_{3}^5\left[(-3x+13)-\left(\frac{-x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]dx.$$
The required area therefore is $$A=A_1+A_2.$$ Can you do the computations of $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$ I_1 = \int^0_{-1} (x+1)-\left(\frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\right)dx$$

$$ I_2=\int^3_{0}(x+1)-\left(\frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\right)dx$$

$$ I_3=\int^5_3 (-3x+13)-\left( \frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3} \right)dx$$

$$ A_{total}=I_1+I_2+I_3=?$$

Also notice that $I_1+I_2$ can be simplified to

$I_{1} + I_2=\int^3_{-1}(x+1)-\left(\frac{-1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}\right)dx$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\int_{-1}^5(f_H(x)-f_L(x))dx,$$
$$f_L(x) = f_3(x) = -\frac13x-\frac13,$$
$$f_H(x) =
\begin{cases}
f_1(x) = x+1, \text{ for } x\in(-1,3)\\
f_2(x) = -3x+13, \text{ for } x\in(3,5).
\end{cases}
$$
$$S=\int_{-1}^3(f_H(x)-f_L(x))dx + \int_{3}^5(f_H(x)-f_L(x))dx,$$
$$S=\int_{-1}^3(f_1(x)-f_3(x))dx + \int_{3}^5(f_2(x)-f_3(x))dx.$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $f_H, f_L$?

Comment: High and Low bounds of curvilinear trapezoid.